# Creating Final Cut Pro/Professional-like interfaces

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, finalcut

I'm in the process of creating an OSX application to be used by professionals, and want to adopt the dull/gray look of Final Cut Studio and other professional-use applications. I want the interface to be toned down, to be less distracting while trying to create the rich content, probably similar to Apple's rationality, and I think is justification to break away from standard HIG.

I was wondering if anyone has done something similar, and has any pointers or examples.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The look and feel of Apple's "pro" applications is defined in ProKit, which is a private system framework located in the system `PrivateFrameworks` folder. ProKit extends several of the AppKit classes such as `NSWindow` and `NSButton` with `NSProWindow`, `NSProButton`, etc. Because ProKit is private, Apple can change it at any time without notice, so you should always be cautious when using it.

Comment: (And avoid it entirely if you're shipping in the Mac App Store)